# Does Ethereum provide any mailing mechanism when a transaction is completed?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

For example, when we are using [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html), there is a mailing mechanism that when a submitted job is completed it sends a mail to e-mail address(defined by the job submitter) that telling the submitted job is completed.

Is there any similar mechanism for Ethereum (public and/or private chain), or any tool that is developed for that which will send email to msg.sender's email address when their submitted transaction is deployed, passed, completed etc.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are after sits at the application/client layer. Take a look at `EtherPing` as an example of such an application.

> EtherPing is a web application that sends you notifications when an
>   Ethereum account of your choosing receives a transaction. This could
>   be one of your contracts, your own Ethereum wallet or another account
>   just for the hell of it.

Over time it is likely that such functionality will be supported natively in mainstream wallets. Meanwhile, you may need to shop around for a standalone app such as the one above.

Comment: `EtherPing` project is not active anymore @zanzu